# Retrieve the current input value from lightning-record-picker when user presses "ENTER"

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I am using lightning-record-picker + lightning-pill to allow for selecting user email records.

I am able to get the current value of the record picker by using the "onchange" event. However, I also need to be able to detect when, for example, the user presses "ENTER" and get the current value of the input on the record picker so I can also create a pill for that (to allow for the user to input emails that are not in Salesforce).

Here's the relevant code:

html:

```
<template>
<lightning-record-picker label={labelValue} lwc:ref="recordPickerRef" placeholder="Search..."
    object-api-name={pickerObjectApiName} display-info={displayInfo} matching-info={matchingInfo}
    onchange={handleSelected} onkeyup={handleKeyPressed} onerror={handleError}>
</lightning-record-picker>
<lightning-pill-container items={selectedRecords} onitemremove={handleItemRemove}>
</lightning-pill-container>
```

JS handlers:

```
handleSelected(event) {
    this.currentSelectedRecord = event.detail.recordId;
    this.refs.recordPickerRef.clearSelection();
 }


  // if the user presses ENTER and its a valid email, accept it anyway
  handleKeyPressed(event) {

    if (event.key==='Enter' && this.refs.recordPickerRef.value.length > 0) {
      this.selectedRecords = [...this.selectedRecords, {
        type: 'icon',
        label: `(${event.target.value})`,
        name: 'iconpill',
        iconName: 'standard:people',
        alternativeText: event.target.value,
        email: event.target.value,
      }];

      this.refs.recordPickerRef.clearSelection();
    }
  }
```

I can also see the email is somewhere on the DOM but it is inaccessible by all other means I'm aware of, e.g. this.template.querySelector and this.template.querySelectorAll.

[image: lightnin record picker input value in DOM]

Is there any hope of getting this to work using the Salesforce component or do I have to go the custom route?